# Update stopped appearing from Start search

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

I am using Windows 10, and I used to be able to search for "update" and it would show me Windows Update, but for some reason it stopped appearing either after the latest update or after I installed Visual Studio. I don't want to get to Windows Update by jumping through loops. Is there any way to bring back the Start search for "update"?
 [image: winupdate]

Comment: What build, after you tried rolling back, and uninstall VS

Comment: @Ramhound it is build 10049, and yes I have just uninstalled Visual Studio. Still getting this issue. I could try refreshing my PC tonight.

Comment: the desktop WU is removed. Use the settings app now